# Log4j Class missing on Weblogic

Tags: log4j, weblogic, classnotfoundexception

I have deployed a war file on Oracle Weblogic. War files contain all the required libraries in WEB-INF/lib. But whenever I am trying to visit my webpage, it gives error of

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger.

[image]

Comment: double check: Does log4j.jar have org/apache/log4j/Logger ?

Comment: Yes, the jar file have the Logger.class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. One of my custom library using log4j, that one was not able to find log4j. So I created the jar including log4j and its working.

Answer (score 0):

try adding to weblogic.xml :

```
 <container-descriptor>
      <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
 </container-descriptor>
```

(Although this may cause secondary issues with JSF jar's.)